# Stopping Supervisor doesn't stop Celery workers

Tags: python, django-celery, supervisord

How do I ensure sub-processes are stopped when I stop Supervisord?

I'm using Supervisord to run two Celery workers. The command for each worker is:

```
command=/usr/local/myapp/src/manage.py celery worker --concurrency=1 --loglevel=INFO
```

When I start supervisord, they run perfectly, but when I run `sudo service supervisord stop`, it reports my workers stop:

```
celery_1: stopped
celery_2: stopped
```

However, when I run `ps aux | grep celery` I see they're still running:

```
www-data 27667  0.0  1.5 318420 64360 ?        S    10:45   0:00 manage.py celery worker --concurrency=1 --loglevel=INFO
www-data 27668  0.0  1.5 318420 318416 ?        S    10:45   0:00 manage.py celery worker --concurrency=1 --loglevel=INFO
```

Comment: Hey @Certin, did you come to a solution for this?

Comment: would be interested in a solution as well ..

Comment: Cerin: Did you find a solution for that ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i believe stopping the supervisor service stops the supervisor daemon, not the supervisor process that is managing your celeryworkers

`supervisorctl stop all` should allow you stop the workers, and also allow you to start/restart them

http://supervisord.org/running.html#running-supervisorctl

Comment: The signal that supervisor sends to the celery workers is not going to kill them immediately, if they are still processing tasks at that moment they will keep running until those tasks are done. So it might take a long time for your workers to shut down even after calling `supervisorctl stop all`

Answer (score 9):

The reason I ended up here is that when I was using supervisor to start and stop my celery processes, the celery workers were not stopping, which lead to an accumulation of workers.

I tried various settings in supervisor, such as stopsignal, and killasgroup. None of them stopped the workers.

At this point, it appears that the celery process does not send signals to the workers when it is stopped.

What I ended up doing was to add:

```
ps auxww | grep 'celery worker' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

to my scripts. This is from [the celery docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#id2)

At the end of this command, I tried kill -TERM instead of kill -9, hoping that would kill the processes more gracefully. But that always left one process.

Comment: You should rather use `pgrep`. Using `ps | grep` may have some issues such as the grep process being itself in the list. `pgrep -f 'celery worker' | xargs kill -9` or simply `pkill -f 'celery worker'`.

Comment: I added the stopasgroup=true to the [program:x] section of supervisor (v4.2.0) and it worked as a charm. Might be more favorable then manual intervention in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but it seams like in this case, supervisor is managing sh scripts. Not python threads. Can you display the `ps auxf | grep celery` , while supervisord are running? May be editing of the command, like this: `command=python /path/to/manage.py ...`, will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in your supervisord.log. Maybe supervisord is sending a SIGKILL to celery? If it is, try to increase the timeout (e.g. stopwaitsecs=600).

> https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/102

Answer (score 1):

I've had such issues with django channels, settings `stopasgroup=true` in suppervisor config ([as suggested here](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/102)) fixed the issue. I don't understand why, however.